# Android Layout xml file should derive all properties of a view from styles.xml

Tags: android, android-styles

This is my layout.xml derives all view parameters from styles.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/DataContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/df_flight_logo"
        style="@style/FlightLOGO"
        />


    <TextView
     android:id="@id/flight_name"
        style="@style/FlightName"
        />

    <TextView
     android:id="@id/flight_price"
        style="@style/FlightPrice"
        />      

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my styles.xml

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="DataContainer">
        <item name="android:layout_height">125dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FlightLOGO">
        <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
         <item name="android:layout_weight">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FlightName">
        <item name="android:layout_height">32dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#b2b2b2</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FlightPrice">
        <item name="android:layout_height">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">18dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#b2b2b2</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

So Should i place all view attributes(width,height,margin,padding) to styles.xml? or properties for specific view(button styles, text styles) to styles.xml?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment explaining what you are trying to do, you should use dimens instead. They are resources like strings.

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="title_size">32sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And for example usage with `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"/>
```

Now you have different dimens.xml files for different screen sizes, but layout stays the same!

An example is here

http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/appendix-c-everything-about-sizes-and-dimensions-in-android/

Comment: By placing all attributes to syles.xml, I want to use same layout.xml for different size devices. Having different styles.xml for different size devices. Is this design approach is good?

Comment: This is my Text View  <TextView
    style="@style/PriceDetails"
   />     This is my styles.xml <style name="PriceDetails">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>     Is this approch good?
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/title_size</item>
    </style>

Comment: It's ok if you want to have several TextViews like this, otherwise not.